# Swipeleft /-right gets executed twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, swipe

I have a html file containing the following code:

```
<div class='admTeaserreihe inactive'>

     <article class="admEmpfehlungTeaser">
           <figure>
                 <img src="url" alt="" />
            </figure>
            <h2>Heading</h2>
            <div class="admEmpfehlungText"><p>text</p>
            </div>
            <a href="url">mehr Infos</a>
     </article>
</div>
```

With multiple article tags, which are rendered dynamically.
To browse through the articles on a mobile device I added jquerymobile.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if($(".admTeaserreihe").length){
        $( document ).on( "swipeleft", ".admTeaserreihe article", function( event ) {
             $(".pfeilRechts").click();
             alert('links');
        });
        $( document ).on( "swiperight", ".admTeaserreihe article", function( event ) {
            $(".pfeilLinks").click();
            alert('rechts');
        });
    }
}
```

The problem is, that the events get called twice. 
For example, if I swipe to the left I get two alerts and the click also gets executed twice.

I can't figure out why the event is fired twice. 
The Jquery Code is on the very end of the html page.

I could do a workaround like only executing the code inside the swipe functions once in one second or something, but I rather want to understand why these functions get called twice.

Edit: The problem was, that document.ready got invoked twice. Thats why the `<article>`s had multiple events.

Comment: Why are you firing swipeleft/swiperight events on document?
Can you make a working fiddle for this?

Comment: I changed it to `$( ".admTeaserreihe article").on( "swipeleft", function( event ) {`but it didn't change anything. I will see wether I can recreate that behaviour on fiddle.

Comment: On fiddle everything works as expected. The events only get called once. http://jsfiddle.net/4qz9mn3g/1/

Comment: Ok i found another solution: document.ready got executed twice. To avoid this, I moved it in another .js file and included it in the head.